# Output XHTML with DB2 XMLTRANSFORM Function

Tags: xslt, xhtml, db2

Can the DB2 XSLTRANSFORM function output HTML which retains the closing tags for empty elements? The same transform I am using in the database works perfectly with other XSLT processors. I am only having a problem when I use it with the XSLTRANSFORM function in DB2. For example,

I need this:

```
<div class="img"></div>
```

Not this:

```
<div class="img" />
```

This is a snippet of the transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" 
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml11-20010531/DTD/xhtml11-flat.dtd" />

<xsl:template match="*">
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT XSLTRANSFORM (XMLDATA USING 
   (SELECT XSLTRANSFORMDOC 
   FROM ds.XSLTRANSFORMS 
   WHERE XSLTRANSFORMID = 15) AS VARCHAR(32672)) 
FROM ds.XMLTAB
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Script tag. So to work around this I would add dummy text in between the tag.
Example: <acronym attr="...">dummy-text</acronym>

Checkout this [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023852.html) about other auto transformations by DB2: